# Nginx rewrite subfolder to subfolder

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have been having issues redirecting an old subfolder entirely to a new subfolder.  I need to have both /old and /old/ go to /new and /new/ respectively

I also need to have any parameters followed after /old/blah/blah2/ to /new/blah/blah2/ so just basically replacing old with new no matter whats called.  The below is the closest I can get.

```
    location /account/ {
       rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal/$1 permanent;
     }
```

Example of an actual URL:

www.domain.com/account/index.php?loend=true&cmd=callback&module=8
needs to be
www.domain.com/portal/index.php?loend=true&cmd=callback&module=8

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you try rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ /portal/$1; ? No need to put it into location /account/ { ... } –  Guillaume Filion Jul 24 at 19:00

Using just: rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ /portal/$1;
without specifying the location has resolved all issues

Answer (score 0):

Its should work but you're missing $ sign in it. 
Here is corrected a bit code

```
rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal$1 redirect;
```

or

```
rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal$1 last;
```

or

```
rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal$1;
```

Than reload config of nginx

```
service nginx reload
```

here is source site.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/301-redirect-nginx

Comment: That did the trick thank you, the only problem I am facing though is with an url like:

https://www.domain.com/account/index.php?loend=true&cmd=callback&module=8

This throws a 404, it doesn't redirect to https://www.domain.com/portal/index.php?loend=true&cmd=callback&module=8

Comment: okay. than try to remove redirect from line. so its look like `rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal$1;`

Comment: Still doesn't work, I noticed its only when using index.php, if I go to, for example: https://www.domain.com/account/?cmd=cart&action=add&id=81

it will redirect without issue but it seems anytime index.php is thrown in the mix, it fails with a 404

Comment: Aren't you just missing a trailing slash? ie: `rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal/$1 permanent;`

Comment: The problem is that you're redirecting `/account/index.php` to `/portalindex.php`, you need to add a slash in between. :)

Comment: I am using:

        `location /account/ {`
        `rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ https://$server_name/portal/$1 permanent;`
        `}`

and it gives me a 404 when going to:

https://www.domain.com/account/index.php?loend=true&cmd=callback&module=8

Comment: The problem is literally just with adding /index.php, if I remove index.php, it will always redirect to /portal but with /index.php there, it just 404's

Comment: Can you try `rewrite ^/account/(.*)$ /portal/$1;` ? No need to put it into `location /account/ { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems more of a redirect than a rewrite, I would use return

```
location ^~ /account(.*) {
  return 301 https://$server_name/portal$1$is_args$query_string;
}
```

The `$is_args$query_string` is to append any query string like you mentioned  in one of the comments `loend=true&cmd=callback&module=8` and also mind that if the `$server_name` is the same name of `server_name` you can replace it with `$http_host` and keep it dynamic.